# How to escape characters in part of a JSON POST request with CURL?

Tags: json, shell, post, curl, postmark

So, I'm trying to use a service called Postmark to send a formatted HTML email. They have some API documentation [here](http://developer.postmarkapp.com/developer-build.html), and they give this example on how to use CURL:

```
$: curl -X POST "http://api.postmarkapp.com/email" \
-H "Accept: application/json" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-H "X-Postmark-Server-Token: ed742D75-5a45-49b6-a0a1-5b9ec3dc9e5d" \
-v \
-d "{From: 'sender@example.com', To: 'receiver@example.com', Subject: 'Postmark test', HtmlBody: '<html><body><strong>Hello</strong> dear Postmark user.</body></html>'}"
```

So, that's all good and works just fine when I use my own token. The problem is when I add my own HtmlBody. If I send a simple message, it works just fine. As soon as I add certain special characters, it breaks. For example, if I do something like this:

```
-d "{From: 'sender@example.com', To: 'receiver@example.com', Subject: 'Postmark test', HtmlBody: '<!DOCTYPE html><html><body><strong>Hello</strong> dear Postmark user.</body></html>'}"
```

It breaks because of the `!`. How can I fix this?

---

**UPDATE**: As *sourcejedi* pointed out I am running this from the shell (bash), so the `!` issue makes sense to me now. I moved the JSON string to a separate file called email.json and loaded that using `-d @email.json`. That worked for a simple email with `<!DOCTYPE>`, but I'm still getting the following error when I try to load the full HTML:

```
{"ErrorCode":402,"Message":"Received invalid JSON input."}
```

I believe this has to do with some other special characters. I get the same error when I use `--data-urlencode @email.json`.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `--data-urlencode`, so it should be like `curl -X POST --data-urlencode`

When I tested on my end..

```
* About to connect() to api.postmarkapp.com port 80 (#0)
*   Trying 50.56.54.211... connected
> POST /email HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.23.1 (x86_64-pc-win32) libcurl/7.23.1 OpenSSL/0.9.8r zlib/1
.2.5
> Host: api.postmarkapp.com
> Accept: application/json
> Content-Type: application/json
> X-Postmark-Server-Token: ed742D75-5a45-49b6-a0a1-5b9ec3dc9e5d
> Content-Length: 164
```

Comment: Still seems to break on me an just returns:
    -bash: !DOCTYPE: event not found

Comment: I just tested the same on my end. it works fine.. are you sure that you are receiving the error.. see the test output I got. I also got the application error `Bad or missing server or user API token` as I am using the wrong server token which is expected.

Answer (score 3):

> Still seems to break on me an just returns: -bash: !DOCTYPE: event not found

That's an error from the bash shell.  You would need to escape the ! as \! yourself.  But you'd be better off reading from a file, I think.  Instead of `-d data` use `-d @datafile`.  (Or `-d @-` to read from stdin).

Comment: In this case, would I just put the whole JSON string in a file?

Comment: @ralphthemagician Yes, that should work.  So long as you don't try to create it from the shell using "echo", because then you would have the exact same problem :).  ("cat", or a console-based editor would be fine).

Comment: I tried it. It works. Sorta. The ! is no longer a problem, but I'm getting "ErrorCode":402,"Message":"Received invalid JSON input." when I try to use the full HTML markup. I think it has something to do with the {} in the style section. Seems to be a step in the right direction though.

Comment: Can't really guess the problem without knowing the input.  But it shouldn't be hard to find a way to validate JSON syntax.  If one doesn't come to mind, just search & you'll find a web-based validator.

Answer (score 3):

I once received the same error when posting JSON data. what I did was enclosed the data with a single quote and use double quote for a string:

so from:

```
-d "{From: 'sender@example.com', To: 'receiver@example.com', Subject: 'Postmark test', HtmlBody: '<html><body><strong>Hello</strong> dear Postmark user.</body></html>'}"
```

use:

```
-d '{From: "sender@example.com", To: "receiver@example.com", Subject: "Postmark test", HtmlBody: "<html><body><strong>Hello</strong> dear Postmark user.</body></html>"}'
```

hope this helps.